# Replace layer in pretrained Pytorch model

Tags: python, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I want to replace the linear layer of the [3D Resnet](https://pytorch.org/hub/facebookresearch_pytorchvideo_resnet/), which can be downloaded from the pytorch hub.

I can get the name of the linear layer by using the following code:

```
for name, layer in model.named_modules():
    if isinstance(layer, torch.nn.Linear):
        print(name, layer)
```

> blocks.5.proj Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=400, bias=True)

I cannot simply use `model.blocks.5.proj = nn.Linear(2048, 10)`, because the `.5.` throws me a syntax error. Instead I tried to iterate over the modules and replace the linear layer:

```
for name, layer in model.named_modules():
    if isinstance(layer, torch.nn.Linear):
        model._modules[name] = torch.nn.Linear(2048, 10)
```

For some reason, this also doesn't work. Instead, it simply creates an additional linear layer with the same name:

> blocks.5.proj Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=400, bias=True)

> blocks.5.proj Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=10, bias=True)

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

The integer from the printed layer indicates that `blocks` is an `nn.Sequential` module. You can access a specific layer in the `nn.Sequential` module with regular array indexing.

Try something like:

```
blocks[5].proj = torch.nn.Linear(2048, 10)
```